# Passing variable to Octobercms blogPosts component

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

On Octobercms blogPosts component i want to pass a variable. I want to change postsPerPage value using:

```
{variable name="blog_postnumber" label="postnumber" tab="postnumber" type="number"}{/variable}
```

on static layout. So i want to be able to change postsPerPage component value with this field on static Pages.

I use a partial with blogPosts component. On component postsPerPage field i insert the variable.

```
postsPerPage = "{{ blog_postnumber }}"
```

Then i try to insert a number in my field on my static page but is not working. Any idea on how can i pass variables on component?

Comment: where this field is rendered `blog_postnumber` can you share details

Comment: I render this field on static layout.htm using {variable name="blog_postnumber" label="postnumber" tab="postnumber" type="number"}{/variable}. I want to be able to change postsPerPage component value using the this field on my static Pages

Comment: I edited my post to make more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: ok and where do you include your `blogPosts` component can you also share that detail

Comment: I use a partial with blogPosts component. Inside that partial i want to be able to pass variables on component.

Comment: yes i got that part, but where you are including that partial is it on static page layout, just asking because in my local i can reproduce and give you answer

Comment: On static page layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really tricky that your passed variable/property to component `will be used or not`. if that property is fetched in component's `onRender` method it will be used. if its used on `onRun` then it will not be used. ( its OctoberCMS Design )

> for `blogPosts` component its in `onRun` so when you pass property like this `{% component 'blogPosts' postsPerPage="2" %}` it will not be used, But To handle this we need other work-around

---

> **(1)** for the component `blogPosts` you included in partial you need to use property from param. check screen shot.

[image]

> **(2)** In you Static layout's **Code section** you need to add this code

```php
public function onStart() {
    $statiPage = $this->page->apiBag['staticPage'];
    // default posts per page
    $defaultBlogPost = 5;
    if(isset($statiPage->viewBag['blog_postnumber'])) {
        // fetching value from the page field
        $defaultBlogPost = intVal($statiPage->viewBag['blog_postnumber']);
        $router = $this->getRouter();
        // combine with existing params
        $router->setParameters(['myBlogPerPage' => $defaultBlogPost] + $router->getParameters());
    }               
}
```

[image]

And in markup part field

```
{variable name="blog_postnumber" label="postnumber" tab="postnumber" type="number"}{/variable}
```

[image]

> **(3)** Now you can start using it set variable value we set it by default **5** in code section, to override it specify value in page's postnumber field section

[image]

It will start working.

If any doubts please comment.

Comment: Hardik Thank you for this Excellent Tutorial! When i use {variable ....{/variable} markup everything is working fine. Do you know how can i make te same using repeater groups? using {repeater name="sections" groups="~/themes/..../fields.yaml" tab="Fields"}{/repeater} markup?

Comment: if you use repeater you will get multiple values so how do we find you need which value, still if you can use `dd($statiPage->viewBag);` in code section where we used `$defaultBlogPost` just dump output and you can check values and use values accordingly.

Comment: still if you face issue please create new question explaining how you wan to use that repeater field values and what are fields etc.. so i can assist you more.

Comment: Thank you Hardik. I created other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421938/passing-variable-to-octobercms-blogposts-component-using-a-repeater-markup