# Passing variable to Octobercms blogPosts component using a Repeater markup

Tags: laravel, octobercms

On Octobercms `blogPosts` component I want to pass a variable. I want to change `postsPerPage` value using:

```
{repeater name="fields" groups="~/themes/demo/myfields.yaml" tab="MyFields"}
{/repeater}
```

on static layout.

myfields.yaml

```
blogfield:
    name: Blog Field
    description: My Blog Field
    fields:
        fields_blog_number:
            label: Posts Number
            type: number
            span: right
```

And I render it with:

```
{% for field in fields%}
...
{% endfor %}
```

So i want to be able to change `postsPerPage` component value with this field on static Pages.

I use a partial with `blogPosts` component.

I try to insert a number in my field on my static page but is not working. Any idea on how can I pass variables on component?

Comment: can you share `myfields.yaml` file content as well

Comment: I edit my post so now i include yaml file

Comment: Hello! I guess this is not possible using a repeater. Am i right?