# OctoberCMS - Rainlabs Blog plugin - foreach category display blog posts

Tags: php, laravel, blogs, octobercms

Hello I want to have multiple categories on one page (as a preview).
Example:

```
Category 1 
POST1, POST2...

Category 2 
POST1, POST2... 

Category 3 
POST1, POST2...
...
```

There can be many categories, so  I want to loop through them and then displaying posts depending on actual category.

My blog component look like this:

```
[blogPosts categoriesPreview]
pageNumber = "{{ page }}"
categoryFilter = "top-recipes"
postsPerPage = 4
noPostsMessage = "No posts found"
sortOrder = "published_at desc"
categoryPage = "recipes-category"
postPage = "recipes-detail"
```

Best way to solve this is pass category to "categoryFilter" in component, like this:

```
{% component 'categoriesPreview' categoryFilter= category.name %}
```

But it's not working... I have no idea how to solve this. Please help :)

Comment: you can check this ans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347814/passing-variable-to-octobercms-blogposts-component/55392293#55392293 it may help you how to pass it and make it work.

Comment: THX, for your comment. Will try that this evening... Anyway, is there some other solutions to do this, without to change Blog plugin?

Comment: no we are not changing blog plugin in any way with that solution. please try it if you ace any issue comment it, we will solve it

Comment: @HardikSatasiya When I was trying to do it like in the answer, I realize that every category has posts already in object :O
So all I need to do is:
{% set catPosts = category.posts %} that's all! But still I'm really thankful for your advice.

Comment: ohk, I didn't look question that way my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future generation (or just for future myself :)) To display all posts depends on category. Simple use [blogCategories] component. Every category has all blog posts already in object, so its not necessary to call another (post list) component with category filter passed to them.